# how to create a selection box?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

please help create selectBox adminpaneli. I use: 
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms.models import ChoiceField
from django import forms

CHOICES = ('volvo', 'saab', 'opel', 'audi', 'cyan',)


class Sponsors(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    background_color = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CHOICES)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from sponsors.models import Sponsors


class sponsorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['title', 'link', 'background_color']  
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ['title']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Спонсор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Спонсоры'        


admin.site.register(Sponsors, sponsorsAdmin)
```

As a result, the administration panel are only visible fields "id", "title", "link". but the field "background_color" is not visible. It also does not exist in the DB.

I need to field "background_color" in adminpanel looked something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select):

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the `background_color` field to your model, you should subclass ModelForm to include that field.

```
class Sponsors(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=100)


CHOICES = ('volvo', 'saab', 'opel', 'audi', 'cyan',)


class SponsorsForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sponsors

    background_color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)


class sponsorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    form = SponsorsForm
```